# Capybara not clicking link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I am trying to run these tests:

```
describe "Selecting Assets Tour" do
    context "when logged in as client" do
        it "should run through all steps" do
            visit tours_path
            click_link("Selecting Assets")
            binding.pry
            expect(page).to have_content 'Selecting an Asset'

        end
    end
end
```

but it fails, but when i insert the binding.pry and manually type in
`click_link("Selecting Assets")`

then exit out of the `binding.pry` then the test passes, but otherwise.. it does not click the link on its own..

I've tried other variations such as: `find('#start-assets-tour').click`  and `click_on`  but the result is the same.  Really not sure at this point why it wont click the link when i run the tests normally, any help would be greatly appreciated

using rails 4

if i havnt provided enough information, please let me know.

EDIT:  my view looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-tour">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tour-header">Site Tours</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% if current_user.client_limited? || current_user.client_full? %>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <%= link_to "Changing Focus", "/", :id => "start-focus-tour" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "Selecting Assets", "/", :id => "start-assets-tour" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "Viewing Asset Details", "/", :id => "start-view-asset-tour" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "Lightbox", "/tours", :id => "start-lightbox-tour" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "Changing Your Viewing Options", "/", :id => "start-navigation-display-tour" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

the id #start-assets-tour  triggers the start of a bootstrap tour, thats the click that is not happening, automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen experienced this kind of your problem before. I happened to fix mine fortuitously by maximizing the browser window just before I ask Capybara to click the element I want. Just add `page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize` like this

```
describe "Selecting Assets Tour" do
  context "when logged in as client" do
    it "should run through all steps" do
      visit tours_path
      page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
      click_link("Selecting Assets")
      expect(page).to have_content 'Selecting an Asset'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find('#start-assets-tour').click_link('Selecting Assets')
```

provided that you have something like this in your view ( I used HAML):

```
=link_to 'Selecting Assets', :id => 'start-assets-tour'
```

If your link is under another element, let's say a div

```
%div#other_id
 =link_to 'Selecting Assets', :id => 'start-assets-tour'
```

you could write something like this:

```
within('#other_id') do
 find('#start-assets-tour').click_link('Selecting Assets')
end
```

If this does not help, maybe you should post your view's content, so that I can give a more specific answer.

Comment: thanks for giving it a go, it didnt work. But I have added the code that is in my view to help with clarification.